# How combined my templatetags and base filter |linebreaksbr

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a problem with right sidebar in that site:
http://antonigin.pythonanywhere.com/

I need to create linebreaks in text. I can add that in post, that's not a problem. But sidebar using my tag.

```
@register.simple_tag
def notetitle(value):
    note = Note.objects.get(pk=value)
    return note.title

@register.simple_tag
def notetext(value):
    note = Note.objects.get(pk=value)
    return note.text
```

I create that template:

```
{% load note_def %}
    {% block note %}

        <h1>{% notetitle 2 %}</h1>
        <p>{% notetext 2 %}</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

I need a filter |linebreaksbr. And i dont know, how to insert this.

Of course, i can send value with my note in every view and insert {% content block %} in every templates, but if i will want change sidebar, that's take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use a single tag that returns the note, ie:

template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_note(value):
    note = Note.objects.get(pk=value)
    return note
```

template:

```
{% load note_def %}
    {% block note %}
        {% get_note 2 as note %}
        <h1>{{ note.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ note.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

As an added benefit you now only need half the db queries ;)

NB : for django < 1.9 you'll have to use an `assignment_tag` instead, cf the doc for your exact version.